# .htaccess redirect has query string, but misses file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm working on permanently redirecting all my links from http://www.example.com/forum/ to http://forum.example.com/. The problem is that only the query string is used, not the actual file to load.

As you can see from my following examples, the new link lacks the file in the url, but has the query string.

**Example 1: (Failed)**

Link from: http://example.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1

Is sent to: http://forum.example.com/?mode=viewprofile&u=258

**Example 2: (Failed)**

Link from: http://example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1&start=1

Is sent to: http://forum.example.com/?f=1&t=1&start=1

**This is my .htaccess file (Placed inside www/forum/)**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/.*$ http://forum.example.com
```

The subfolder /forum/ is the only links that should be redirected. We are just moving the forum to a new subdomain. I'm not familiar with htaccess, so please excuse me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/(.*) http://forum.domain.com/$1
```

I have no idea why it works, but I found out using the good old trail and error.